# Использование try-catch в цикле "FOR" в java

Tags: java, for, try-catch

Смотрите, пользователь заполняет массив чисел (любого знака) в цикле. Не получается так сделать try-catch, что если, например, он введёт неправильно 5-ое число, чтобы в консоли 
1) вывелось сообщение о неверном формате; 
2) ввод продолжился с того места(с той итерации), на которой возникло исключение.

```
int[] numbers = new int[NUM];       

for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) 
{    

 try
 {
    System.out.print((i + 1) + ": ");
    numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
 }
 catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex)
 {
       System.out.println("Wrong input! It should be a number");
       continue;
 }

}
```

Пока получается что-то такое:

```
1: r
Wrong input! It should be a number
2: Wrong input! It should be a number
3: Wrong input! It should be a number
```

Comment: В блоке catch сделайте i--

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так:

```
 {
       System.out.println("Wrong input! It should be a number");
       i--;
 }
```

Comment: Исправил. При вводе буквы циклится вывод вот этого говна
1: Wrong input! It should be a number

Comment: А где вы выполняете ввод данных? Надо в том же цикле

Comment: Так он в try блоке

Comment: Вот он: numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();

Comment: Я так понимаю, что nextInt выдает старое число постоянно, отсюда такой вывод программы

Comment: Проблему решил так: Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) добавил в try в начало, чтобы после каждого неверного ввода просто новый scanner создавался и про тот неправильный ввод больше не было упоминаний

Answer (score 0):

Использование блока try-catch в логике приложения - плохой тон. try-catch работает медленно, и он не предназначен для реализации логики, а для отлова исключений. По этой же причине Scanner работает медленно, так как в своей логике использует try-catch (напр. метод hasNextInt()).
Более правильно будет осуществлять проверку, например, по регулярным выражениям.

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int[] numbers = new int[NUM];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        String s = null;
        try {
            s = reader.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (isNumber(s)) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(s);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input! It should be a number");
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Метод проверки введенной строки:

```
public static boolean isNumber(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return input.matches("^([-+])?\\d+$");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот работающий цикл:

```
int[] numbers = new int[NUM];

                for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {

                    try
                    {
                        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                        System.out.print((i + 1) + ": ");
                        numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
                    }
                    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Wrong input! It should be a number");
                        i--;
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Создавать каждый раз новый объект `scanner` не хорошо